# Push object with angular foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, foreach, angularjs-scope

I have a data type object like this :

```
["Tag Name13", "Tag Name12"]
```

But if i push with this script :

```
var list_tag = [];

angular.forEach(retrive_data.tags, function(item){
   list_tag.push(item.label);
});

$scope.tag = list_tag;
```

The output in console.log is

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

And I open the structure like this :

```
Array[3]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
```

Yes, my data has pushed but data the structure is changed and i can't process in the next step. am I wrong ? give me solution please , Thanks

**UPDATED**

```
Array[2]
0 : "Tag Name13"
1 : "Tag Name12"
```

[image: UPDATED]

```
Array[2]

_id:"58a28112a6551f5b8a4fc0d3"
active:0
created_at:"2017-02-14 11:01:22"
description:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci13"
image:"http://placehold.it/300x30013"
label:"Tag Name13"
meta_description:"Meta Description Tag Name13"
meta_keyword:"Meta Keywoprd Tag Name13"
meta_title:"Meta Title Tag Name13"
priority:100
related:"[]"
thread_count:0
thread_ids:Array[1]
updated_at:"2017-03-03 11:53:20"
url:"tag-name13"
```

Comment: post `retrive_data.tags` array

Comment: display your retrive_data.tags object

Comment: You mean, before I push ? @Gaurav

Comment: yes initial retrive_data.tags object

Comment: I edited my code @Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to take another variable just use scope variable only

Check my code

```
$scope.tags = [];

angular.forEach(retrive_data.tags, function(item){
   $scope.tags.push(item.label);
});

console.log($scope.tags) //output ["Tag Name13", "Tag Name12"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I did exactly. But still not working.

Comment: if object retrive_data.tags provided by you is same then this approach will work fine, may be you are doing some mistake elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var list_tag = [];

 angular.forEach(retrive_data.tags, function(item){
  list_tag.push(item);
});

$scope.tag = list_tag;
```

I think its should be like above

Comment: And then from where i get "Tag Name12" label ? I tried your code but not working

Comment: Btw, I use item.label to get data label tag by id. And if I use just "item" , showing error